# How to get next month date of given date by using nextDate function in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to get next month date of given date by using nextDate function. But result is not as expected. Could you please help what is wrong with code below?

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.hour = 11
dateComponents.minute = 25
dateComponents.second = 0
dateComponents.day = 9

let nextMonthDate = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: 
dateComponents, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)

print("Current Date: \(Date())") // 2018-07-12 07:50:22 +0000

print("nextMonthDate: \(nextMonthDate)") // 2018-08-01 00:00:00 +0000
                                        // expected 2018-08-09 11:25:00 +0000
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Try using `.strict` instead of `.nextTime`.

Comment: thanks @Sweeper . After changing to .strict it is working as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

After changing .nextTime to .strict it is working as I expected.